# Google Play Console Apply for access to production

Tags: android, google-play-console

I've recently created a new Google Play Console account. For this new account, it is now mandatory to have at least 20 closed testings. I have fulfilled all the requirements, but I am still unable to find the option to 'Apply for production.' Am I missing something?
[image: Google Play Console]

Comment: I don't know who decided to do it, but it is a huge pain for me - I don't have testers and 20 friends with desinging to testing something. Google is big pig. I hope the guy who suggested it will go to the hell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally grasped the reason behind this. Only the account owner is eligible to apply for production. Developer or admin accounts cannot initiate the production application process.